# How to import other python modules and packages

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, mrjob

I have the following project structure,

```
work_directory:
    merge.py
    a_package
```

(i.e. a python file `merge.py` and a directory `a_package` under the directory "work_directory")

I wrote a MapReduce job using MRJob in merge.py, in which I need to import `a_package`, like `from a_package import something`.
But I have difficulty uploading `a_package` into hadoop.

I have tried this method(https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/writing-mrjobs.html#using-other-python-modules-and-packages): I wrote

```
class MRPackageUsingJob(MRJob):
    DIRS = ['a_package']
```

and import code from inside a mapper

```
def mapper(self, key, value):
    from a_package import something
```

I also tried this one: https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/setup-cookbook.html#uploading-your-source-tree

But neither of them work, it keeps showing `ImportError: No module named a_package`.

What should I do?

Comment: how do you run the script merge.py? It may be related

Comment: If `merge.py` is not run as __main__ (`python merge.py`), but imported as a module, then you should use relative import like: `from .a_package import something`.

`__init__.py` actually should not matter, because since python 3.3 namespace packages are a thing.

Comment: Thank you for asking. I have another file `main.py` under `work_directory` which runs as *main*. In that file I wrote ```dirname = os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))[0],  cmd = "doas python dirname/merge.py", os.system(cmd)``` to run merge.py. @Syler ,  @TopW3

Comment: Is this an actual code? `dirname` there is never used. In `python dirname/merge.py` it's just a word, not a variable reference.

Also, ultimately, you are still running `python dirname/merge.py` which means that merge.py is running as the __main__ module.

Can you `print` data in `merge.py`? Try printing out `sys.path` to check modules search path and `os.listdir()` to see if a_package dir is actually uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need just create empty file "__init__.py" in folder, what you want to use like a package.
For example:

```
work_directory:
  __init__.py
  merge.py
  a_package
```